# Display file (image) on another file with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, file-upload

I want to upload a file on a page and then display it in another page
Here's my post.jsx (where I want to upload the file):

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next'

export default function postPage({ username }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { msg } = router.query;
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(msg !== undefined);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);


  const handleFileChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
  };

  const handleDismissError = () => {
    setShowError(false);
  };

  return (
    <Layout pageTitle="Se connecter">
      <div className="navbar-signup">
        <div className="left">
          <Link href="/" className="accueil">
            Accueil
          </Link>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <Link href="/signup" className="connexion">
            S'inscrire
          </Link>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='informations'>
        <img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/972878173488447568/1184484661565599825/stickers-muraux-logo-nike.jpg?ex=658c244d&is=6579af4d&hm=e6230816ac8a2b23526abdf6b724d6f0f070f47cc533251ff2f03e04fc564acd&=&format=webp"></img>
      </div>
      <div className="box">
        <br></br>
        {showError && (
        <div className="error-box">
          <p className="error-message">{msg}</p>
          <button onClick={handleDismissError}>Ok</button>
        </div>
      )}
        <p className="signuptitle">Poste Ta Note !</p>
        <form action="/api/post" method="POST">
          <p>Matière :</p>
          <input
            minLength="1"
            name="subject"
            id="subject"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Mathématiques, Anglais etc.."
            required
          ></input>
          <br />
          <p>Moyenne De La Matière :</p>
          <input
            minLength="1"
            name="subjectaverage"
            id="subjectaverage"
            type="number"
            placeholder="10, 15, 17 etc..."
            required
          ></input>
          <br />
          <p>Temps De Révision :</p>
          <input
            minLength="1"
            name="revisiontime"
            id="revisiontime"
            type="text"
            placeholder="aucune, 2h, 15min etc.."
            required
          ></input>
          <br />
          <p>Photo De Ta Feuille :</p>
          <input type="file" name='picture' onChange={handleFileChange}/>
          {selectedFile && (
          <img src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)}></img>
      )}
          <input type="hidden" name="username" value={username}></input>
          <br />
          <br></br>
          <input type="submit" value="Poster" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const req = context.req
  const res = context.res
  let username = getCookie('username', { req, res });
  if (!username) {
      return {
          redirect: {
              permanent: false,
              destination: "/"
          }
      }
  }
  return {
    props: { username },
  }
}
```

here's the backend:

```
import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const username = req.body['username'];
    const subject = req.body['subject'];
    const subjectAverage = req.body['subjectaverage'];
    const revisionTime = req.body['revisiontime'];
    const picture = req.body['picture']

    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("Notes");

      const noteObject = {
        username,
        subject,
        subjectAverage,
        revisionTime,
        picture,
      };


      await db.collection("Notes").insertOne(noteObject);

      res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
}
```

So, I don't really know how I can upload a file and then display it on another page by storing the file in the database, I've been trying for hours and haven't found any solution, can someone help, please?